# simulate up when back button is pressed

Tags: android

I'm working on an android app and recently, I discovered that the default back button `onBackPressed()` produces a **back** behaviour, while the `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` produces an **up** behaviour. And the two have significant differences.

I was wondering if I can simulate the **up** behaviour when I press the hardware back button, so that it navigates **up** instead of **back**. 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried overriding `onBackPressed` and calling `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);` from within it?

Comment: The `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);` is what I was missing. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. The `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);` is what I was missing

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

Overide onOptionsItems Selected

Create a switch case of android.R.id.home 
  Call method onBackPressed();

here is the code

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be doing the opposite of what I wanted. But thanks for the effort though